# Deleting first object in Core Data (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am requesting Core Data to return me its Entity entries in ascending order based on contentid:

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!

let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key:"contentid", ascending:true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

let fetchedResults = managedObjectContent.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [NSManagedObject]
```

How do I delete the first object in Core Data's returned, ascending entries?

I have also tried getting a single object by specifying:

```
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
```

Thinking that this would return an [NSManagedObject], I attempted to then perform:

```
managedObjectContext.deleteObject(fetchedResults)
```

But it threw the error: `cannot invoke method deleteObject with type '([NSManagedObject])'`. What exactly am I doing incorrectly? Do I need to convert `[NSManagedObject]` to `NSManagedObject`, perhaps?

Comment: `[NSManagedObject]` it's an Array which holds `NSManagedObject`'s instances. You can't invoke `deleteObject` on array.

Comment: Ah I see. So what should it be invoked with?

Comment: please see my answer below

Comment: An `NSArray` has a property `firstObject`, which depending on your sort, may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let fetchedResults = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)
if let result = fetchedResults?.first as? NSManagedObject {
    context.deleteObject(result)
}
```

`executeFetchRequest` returns `[AnyObject]?` so you must unwrap it, take first object and cast it to `NSManagedObject`. After that you will be able to perform delete with this object.

Comment: When saving, I am getting the error: "CoreData: error: Mutating a managed object 0x7fecdbcc0390 <x-coredata:///Article/tCEF47CDA-545F-484B-A2E5-72912A74D6CE2> (0x7fecdbcc00e0) after it has been removed from its context."

Comment: It appears that the above error is happening only after I am asking Core Data to return the data sorted. Otherwise it is taking the first item and removing it successfully, but what I really need it to do is remove the entry with the lowest contentid. So I am using the sort method but throws the error...

Answer (score 1):

Try with `managedObjectContext.deleteObject(fetchedResults[0])` 
, checking first that fetchedResults[0] exists.
Also you can use: `managedObjectContext.deleteObject(fetchedResults.first)`

Comment: Thanks Javier. For some reason I am still getting the same console error as written in Kubba's answer. Very strange.

Comment: Is there a way to have this done after having it sort by ascending order?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the first object from the returned array, then use [deleteObject:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/deleteObject:)

You can find a lot of useful information on [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html)

--EDIT--

From Apple Doc

> func executeFetchRequest(_ request: NSFetchRequest,
>                      error error: NSErrorPointer) -> [AnyObject]?
>
> Return Value
>
> An array of objects that meet the criteria specified by
>   request fetched from the receiver and from the persistent stores
>   associated with the receiver’s persistent store coordinator. If an
>   error occurs, returns nil. If no objects match the criteria specified
>   by request, returns an empty array.

Notice the return value of executeFetchRequest is an array, not a NSManagedObject

Comment: Yes, I have attempted using deleteObject and have updated my question above for clarity.

Comment: The part that I'm confused about is that fetchedResults is being returned as an [NSManagedObject]. When being passed to deleteObject, it says that it cannot be invoked with an NSManagedObject, but I thought that is what it is expecting. I went through the docs but still feel I'm totally missing something here...

Comment: It is being returned as a NSManagedObject because you are using the as! operator to convert it